# react native html view displaying space as asterisk

Tags: react-native

Current days I am interested in how to display markdown content in my react native app.Then I came across with `react-native-html-view`.But when I use this with fetched data to create my own custom component It displays all space fractions as an asterisk like `***`.Can anyone help me to solve this collapsible fraction issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use one of this libs

[React Native Markdown Renderer](https://github.com/mientjan/react-native-markdown-renderer)

[React Native Markdown Display](https://github.com/iamacup/react-native-markdown-display)

Comment: I want to thank you bottom of my heart.This is a most remarkable answer that i have ever seen